# How to get http response status code using JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl, sap-commerce-cloud

I am working on Hybris where we have below  property set in web.xml

```
<jsp-config>
 <jsp-property-group>
   <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
      <!-- Disable JSP scriptlets and expressions -->
      <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
      <!-- Remove additional whitespace due to JSP directives -->
      <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
 </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

because of `<scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>`, I am unable to use <% ---code ---- %> in JSP pages. 
I wanted to display the http response status Code(404,403,500)  on .JSP page. I know the script to do the same using <% %> which is given below.

```
<%=HttpStatus.getStatusText(response.getStatus())%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.httpclient.*"%>
```

How can I achieve the same(display the response status code-404,403,500) using by purely using the JSTL tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research I was able to find the simple solution this this problem.

```
<c:out value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.status_code']}" />
```